# How to manually add library to Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos

I would like to use the following library https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream in my Xcode project. Cocoa pods are not an option for me(I get a hundred errors), therefore I would like to add it directly. What is the proper way to add library manually so I can access its functionality?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the library and add all files from Source folder to your project and you can use them. If there is no constraint on other libraries you can use [Socket.IO](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift).

You will not need to import it as you are adding the source files to your target. So you can directly use
 `WebSocket(url: URL(string: "ws://localhost:8080/")!)`

As figured out you can use CocoaPod and update your code and Xcode to latest Swift.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. I got 111 errors with just pasting the files in Source folder:D

Comment: @brumbrum Can you share the screenshot with errors?

Comment: @brumbrum I think this error is due to the library using the different version of swift. Which Xcode are you using?

Comment: aaa, might be. I am using 7.3

Comment: That would also explain why Cocoa pods are not working. Time to upgrade.

Comment: @brumbrum If this is the errors then for sure CocoaPods will not work. So either update Xcode or use the library with lower version.